# How can I show uniform convergence?

Tags: metric-spaces, uniform-convergence

> Let
>
> $f_n(x)=\frac{x^n}{1+x^n},~x\geq 0, ~n\in\mathbb{N}$.
>
> 1.1.: Determine the pointwise limi of $(f_n)$, $x\geq 0$.
>
> 1.2.: Show that the sequence $(f_n)$ is uniformly convergent on  the intervals
>
> $[0,c]$     for $0<c<1$.
>
> $[b,+\infty[$       for $b>1$.
>
> 1.3.: Show that there is no uniform convergence on $[1,+\infty[$.

Learning for an upcoming test and I found this one in some problem sheets.

I never dealt with pointwise convergence so I'm not sure how to proceed here. Is it similar to finding the limit of a sequence which is just a point?

About b: I never heard of uniform convergence so I looked up the wiki entry on it. 'If the speed of the convergence does not depend on x.'

How do I approach this type of problem?

So basically I can't deal with this exercise at all. I'm sorry for the lack of work shown here, but I'm really struggling with metric spaces in general.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking,for what course are you studying? I mean,It sounds strange that you will be facing an exam on issues that you have not become familiar with..And a wiki definition will not really help when tackling a problem such as this one..

Comment: @OttavioConsone 
I'm studying physics. I got math as a subsidiary subject. Our teacher has been hospitalized for the past 5 weeks and since the university doesn't have a substitute teacher yet (we are dangerously understaffed in our department) for us we have to read about the subjects set in this semester on our own.

Comment: Oh,I see..A very challenging situation indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

Check first that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}=f(x)=\begin{cases}0&,\;\;0\le x<1\\{}\\\dfrac12&,\;\;x=1\\{}\\1&,\;\;x>1\end{cases}$$

and for example,  for $\;0\le x\le c<1\;$ :

$$\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}\le c^n$$

and you can apply Wierstrass's M-test with the geometric series.

The case $\;x>1\;$ is similar and I'll let it to you.

Comment: Sorry, for the late response. About the Weierstrass M-Test. Although our textbook states the definition of it it doesn't really give a proof or example of it. Can you tell me if I'm doing this right? 
I was thinking that since $\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}\leq 1$ for $0\leq x<1$, that I would set $M=1$, meaning that it is not uniformly convergent because the geometric series says that it's divergent?

Comment: @Rixton No, that's wrong. Did you read my answer at all? I proved there that there's uniform convergence for $\;0\le x<1\;$ ...

Comment: You're right. But about $x>1$ now: I can't seem to find an $M$ so that I can utilize Weierstrass's M-test. And about $[1,+\infty]$: How come this is not uniform continuous even though $[b,+\infty],~~b>1]$. Does including $1$ really not make it uniform continuous?

Comment: For $\;x\in [b,\infty]\;,\;\;b>1\;$ , observe that **for all** $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$  : $$\left|\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}-1\right|=\frac1{1+x^n}\le\frac1{1+b^n}$$ There can't be **uniform** convergence in $\;[1,\infty]\;$ as the *limit*  function is **not** continuous there

Comment: Last silly quesiton on my part: Why wouldn't the limit function not be continuous in that interval?

Answer (score 1):

1.1 So,here we go..First you will need the definition of Pointwise Convergence.That is:

For any $x\in D$, where $D$ is a domain,and for any $ε>0$,there exists an $N$ such that,for every $n>N$:$∣f_n(x)-f(x)∣<ε$

Also,bear in mind that if $∣$x$∣<1$,then $lim_{n\rightarrow∞}∣$x$∣^t=0$,for any real number $t$ and if $∣x∣>1$,then$∣x∣^t\rightarrow∞$ for any real $t$.

We will show that the given function $f_n(x)$ converges to the function $f(x)=0$ if $0≤∣x∣<1$.

Indeed, notice that $lim_{n\rightarrow∞}∣\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}∣=0$,since $x^n\rightarrow0$.

If $∣x∣>1$ , notice that: $lim_{n\rightarrow∞}∣\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}-1∣=∣\frac{1}{1+x^n}∣=0$. So $f_n$ converges to $f(x)=1$ for $∣x∣>1$

Finally,we check the case for $x=1$. Then $f_n(x)=1/2$ as you immediately verify.